# Why am i getting Installation Error using Yandex?

Tags: docker, yandex-tank

```
$ docker run  direvius/yandex-tank
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/yandex-tank", line 11, in 
        load_entry_point('yandextank==1.9.13', 'console_scripts', 'yandex-tank')()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/cli.py", line 91, in main
        worker = ConsoleTank(options, ammofile)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py", line 285, in __init__
        overwrite_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py", line 256, in load_tank_core
        [load_cfg(cfg) for cfg in config_files] + other_opts + parse_options(cmd_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py", line 91, in load_cfg
        with open(cfg_filename) as f:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'load.yaml'
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create a directory -

```
mkdir yandex-tank
```

put the load.yaml file in the directory. 
See an example

```
phantom:
  address: 203.0.113.1:80 # [Target's address]:[target's port]
  uris:
    - /
  load_profile:
    load_type: rps # schedule load by defining requests per second
    schedule: line(1, 10, 10m) # starting from 1rps growing linearly to 10rps during 10 minutes
console:
  enabled: true # enable console output
telegraf:
  enabled: false # let's disable telegraf monitoring for the first time
```

And docker run, also write new directory here - **youPWD/yandex-tank**

```
docker run     
-v /youPWD/yandex-tank :/var/loadtest     
-v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent     
--net host     
-it direvius/yandex-tank
```